# My code won't parse

Tags: java

I have no idea what's wrong. I have a class project to use three methods to take a user input and tell what primitive type is the smallest that will work for the input, but for some reason when I run the code it turns every input into 0. Here's my code (Main is in a different class):
The code was fixed no need for further answers It was just my novice understanding of syntax.

```
package stuff;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class driver 
{



public static void run() throws IOException
{
System.out.println("Please input a number");
num1 = prompt();
analyze();
}
static long num1;

public static long prompt() throws IOException
 {
 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String Selection1 = input.readLine();
    long num1 = Long.parseLong(Selection1);
    return num1;
 }

public static void analyze() throws IOException
{
System.out.println(num1);
if (num1>=Byte.MIN_VALUE && num1<=Byte.MAX_VALUE) 
{
    System.out.println("you should use a byte");
} 
else if (num1>=Short.MIN_VALUE && num1<=Short.MAX_VALUE) 
{
    System.out.println("you should use a short");
}
else if (num1>=Integer.MIN_VALUE && num1<=Integer.MAX_VALUE)
{
    System.out.println("you should use an integer");
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("you should use a long");
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the value returned by the `prompt` method, y'know.

Instead of just calling `prompt();`, you should assign the value returned to `num1`:

```
num1 = prompt();
```

And the program magically works!

"But wait! In the `prompt` method, I already assigned the parsed long to `num1`! Look!" you shouted.

```
long num1 = Long.parseLong(Selection1);
```

Actually, you're not assigning the parsed value to the `num1` variable you declared at the class level. You are creating a new variable called `num1`!